# More efficient method of passing $routeParams in the same view

Tags: angularjs

I have a button that's passing $routeParams
However this is too slow/clunky as it reloads the entire view by going to the same URL collections.html

Angular

```
  $routeProvider.when('/products/:uId/:mId/productsList', {
        templateUrl: '/views/collections.html',
        controller:  'productsController'
});
```

HTML

```
  <tr> ng-repeat="(key, product) in products">
                <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.value}}</td></tr>
```

Is their a method of passing the $routeParams and loading a partial view
without reloading the entire view to speed things up a bit ?

e.g. ng-include  instead of ng-href

Comment: Here's the button      <a class="btn btn-list tooltip" 
               ng-      href="#!/products/{{currentUser.regUser}}/{{key}}/productsList">
                </a>   Note: I already have CurrentUser as it's from the rootScope  the key variable is what parameter is been selected by the button

Comment: What makes you thing it's slow? Have you measured it, or is it just an assumption? Angular keeps templates in cache. It won't reload collections.html.

Comment: The page/view has a lot of data been passed from various api's
and when I click the button to pass the required  $routeParams 
it reloads the page i.e. a newURL  and waits for the other api feeds to be rendered in teh main view

I only want the $routeParams to be injected into a partial of the view 
to avoid this